# Mobile devices given name of “occam” or “Razor” when viewing network in Windows 7 and later?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking, wireless-router, network-discovery

I’ve encountered various threads, on `support.microsoft.com` and on various Windows support forums, where a user (like myself, today and in the past) has seen an unknown mobile device (represented with an old-school cell phone icon - usually listed as an LG/LGE Nexus 4 or an ASUS Nexus 7, though other non-nexus devices have shown up this way) called `occam` or `Razor`.

In my case today, it turned out to be my roommate’s LG Optimus L9, and the reason it showed up in my network listing is because I had the main wireless network labeled as a `Home` network on my Windows 8.1 Pro (64-bit) desktop, and the “Network Discovery” service was turned on. Once I turned Network Discovery off, I could, of course, no longer see the device.

Some threads have suggested that the appearance of these devices was related to the “Windows Connect Now” service being turned on, other threads have said that it is due to the WPS service being active on the wireless router in question.

My question is: Is it Windows that is assigning these titles `occam` and `Razor`, or some other technology? I’m trying to understand where these names, obviously referring to “[Occam’s Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor),” are coming from, and why.

No one else on the Interwebs has explained it, not that has been indexed by Google or Bing to date.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Nexus Files for Developers](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en) "occam" is a code name for Nexus 4 and "razor" is a code name for Nexus 7.

According to Wikipedia Occam's razor, also called the "law of parsimony", can be interpreted as: *Among competing hypotheses, the one with the fewest assumptions should be selected.* Regarding the code names of the Nexus devices, I interpret "occam" and "razor" as a reminder that the  Android operating systems of the Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 are designed to be parsimonious about power consumption in order to make the battery last longer.

Answer (score 1):

Odd. Seems like this all comes down to Android codenamed—for `android.os.Build.PRODUCT` and [according to this post](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/10/24/lg-nexus-4-benchmark-shows-codenames-of-mako-and-occam-hates-all-over-the-motorola-rumor/); bold emphasis is mine:

> A purported benchmark for the LG Nexus 4 appeared at GLBenchmark this
>   week, showing us some of the dirty details that we were still hoping
>   to get clarification on before the product is unveiled next Monday.
>
> First off, you’ll notice that we have a device name of “mako” which
>   has been known as the codename for some time now. **Second, you’ll
>   notice the word “occam” in the build fingerprint and product, another
>   name that has been tossed around.** In fact, a couple of weeks ago, the
>   tin foil hats came out, and a group of Android enthusiasts jumped to
>   the wild conclusion that there was a better-than-average chance that
>   this was going to be a separate Nexus, probably built by Motorola. You
>   see, because if you Google the term “occam,” you’ll find “Occam’s
>   Razor.” Apparently, that should mean that occam equals RAZR, which
>   equals Motorola phone. Wild, I know. This benchmark, if legit, debunks
>   the hell out of that.
>
> **“Occam” in this case is the build product, a second name attached to
>   all Nexus devices that refers to software builds.** For example, the
>   Verizon Galaxy Nexus runs under codename “toro,” but it’s software
>   builds fall under the name “mysid.” For all GSM Galaxy Nexus variants,
>   you’ll see codename “maguro,” however, each version has a different
>   software build codename like “yakju” or “takju.” Make sense? So
>   “occam” simply ties software to the LG Nexus 4, which is known as
>   “mako.”

Checking here on [the official Google Developer page for “Factory Images for Nexus Devices”](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en) shows that “razor” is the codename for the for Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi).